# How to programmatically disable/enable a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode5, uibarbuttonitem

I currently have a button called `continueButton` that has been assigned to a UIBarButtonItem button in a Storyboard file. I've declared the button as such:

```
- (IBAction)continueButton;
```

When the view loads, I want the button to disable itself, so that there can be no user input unless a command is called that re-enables user input for the button. How would I go about doing this? I'm trying to use the function `[continueButton setEnabled:YES];` to disable/enable the button programmatically, but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: That's not how you declare a UIBarButtonItem. What you want is an IBOutlet to the button in your Storyboard so that you can refer to it. IBAction is for handling a tap or some other gesture on the button.

Comment: What do you find if you run a search for 'uibarbuttonitem disable'?

Comment: You are confusing outlets and actions. They are different. An IBAction is a link between a control and a method that gets called when the control is triggered (usually by a tap, but also by other events like changing the value of a slider.) An IBOutlet is a link from an IB object to your code, so you have a way to refer to the object. As others have suggested, you need to create an outlet link between your bar button item and your view controller class. Then you can use that outlet to enable/disable the item as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't exposed the `UIBarButtonItem` to your code. For the properties of the control to be accessible it either needs to be connected to an `IBOutlet` (bridge between XIB and code) as hw731 said, or created programmatically in the first place. An action is more like binding a method to an event raised by the control.

[image: Example of outlet over action]

If you cant see the option for an `Outlet` or `Outlet` collection when making the connection its likely you are in the `.m` file instead of the `.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through some of the comments, I realized that I wasn't supposed to setup the UIBarButtonItem as a `IBAction` button, but through an `IBOutlet`. After doing so, and reconnecting the button in Storyboards, the command I was trying before, worked.

```
[continueButton setEnabled:NO];
```

or (for enabling the button):

```
[continueButton setEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: If an answer has helped you solve a problem, don't forget to accept one as the answer. Happy coding!